# groovy retrieve def value and assign it to a particular place

Tags: groovy, mule

I'm new to groovy and trying to retrieve value from def and place it to a particular place in another def value. Could anyone  help on this

```
def init = "Hello"
def msg = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report id="${init}"> -- here i want to replace with above value which is Hello>
    <exception code="1">Invalid request</exception>
</report>
"""
```

i'm expecting below output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report id="Hello">
    <exception code="1">Invalid request</exception>
</report>
```

Comment: That should work...  Does it work?  If not, how does it not work?

Comment: its throwing some weird characters in postman client..

Comment: Please give more details of the error and clarify why it is related to Mule.

Comment: If your replacement instead of `Hello` is something, that must be quoted inside XML, you would get messed up things.  E.g. `def init = '"&<>'` will mess things up. So please add the failing example - especially the "werid chars in postman"

Answer (score 0):

Setting the mimeType to application/xml should work.

```
<flow name="xmlFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/groovy" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[def init = "Hello"
    def msg = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <report id="${init}">
        <exception code="1">Invalid request</exception>
    </report>
    """]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: also could you tell how we can refer groovy script from file. I have placed groovy file under src\main\resources